# How to handle address stored in variable with pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I need to help how to handle this situation. 
Variable `DestinationAddress` which contains start value of memory. And I want to use pointer to write to the address the data. Is it OK?

Example:

```
long Data32;
long DestinationAddress;
long *temp;

Data32 = 0x00112233;
DestinationAddress = 0x00280000;
temp = DestinationAddress;
*temp = Data32;
```

Comment: Use code blocks and proper formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example?

Comment: "Is it OK?" You tell me, did you try it?

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  In C++, you can have `constexpr` and smart pointers.  The C language doesn't have these items.  Also, C++ has `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`, which are not in the C language.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Is it in C.

Comment: @tambre: from my point of view it is working but all I found in the documentation is, that pointer tmp = &DestinationAddress and *tmp = any_value, but I am no able to find example, where pointer is filled not with address of the variable but with the value of the variable. So my question is: Can I initialize pointer how I did? It means load value of variable DestinationAddress directly to pointer temp. I am not loading address of the variable. Is it correct?

Comment: It invokes undefined behaviour, thus is not ok from the strict language definition. `temp` points to memory not allocated by the language. You have to provide more details and define what you consider "OK".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your variables are declared as:

```
long Data32;
long DestinationAddress;
long *temp;
```

You may not use

```
temp = DestinationAddress;
```

You may use:

```
temp = &DestinationAddress;
```

Then, using:

```
*temp = Data32;
```

is a valid way to set the value of `DestinationAddress` to `Data32`.

However, the name `DestinationAddress` and the type used to declare it, `long`, don't seem to match. If you want `DestinationAddress` to store an address of a `long`, it needs to be declared as:

```
long* DestinationAddress;
```

If you want to use an integral type instead of a `long*` to store an address, the types to use are [`intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

```
uintptr_t Data32;
uintptr_t DestinationAddress;
uintptr_t* temp;

Data32 = 0x00112233;
DestinationAddress = 0x00280000;
temp = &DestinationAddress;
*temp = Data32;
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

You need to use:

```
long Data32;
uintptr_t DestinationAddress;
long* temp;

Data32 = 0x00112233;
DestinationAddress = 0x00280000;
temp = (long*)DestinationAddress;
*temp = Data32;
```

Comment: @R Sahu   I dont want to set the value of DestinationAddress to Data32. I want to set the memory (actually 0x00280000 which is stored in DestinationAddress) with Data32.

Answer (score 0):

In embedded systems, many hardware registers are located at specific addresses.  The software needs to write to and read from these addresses.

The classic (C style) idiom is:

```
#define USB_STATUS_REGISTER ((uint16_t *) (0x40008250))
uint16_t const * const p_status_register = USB_STATUS_REGISTER;
uint16_t status = *p_status_register;
```

Comment: My address 0x00280000 is RAM memory

Comment: @PepeEsteban: In that case, use the linker to set up a RAM region. Using such addresses in your code is a bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf  I dont know what do you mean to set up the RAM. Do you have any example to show what should I do?

Comment: @PepeEsteban: Read the documentation of your toolchain. Setting a RAM **region** is done in the linker control file normally. For gcc and GNU ld, define a memory region and store a custom section into it. Use `__attribute__` in your code to assign variables to that section. Messing with RAM the way you do is invitation to disaster, if it is also managed by the linker. For hardware-peripheral registers, use the header files from your MCU manufacturer.

Comment: @Olaf  it is special type of RAM memory called FlexRAM and is not used as a normal RAM where is the stack or any other loaded functions. And it is not linked in linker file. So there is no collision or overflow when running the application.

Comment: @PepeEsteban: That does not change anything.

Comment: @Olaf I believe that you are right, but I am just asking "why" is it invitation to disaster? Please explain to me what can happened? I just simply dont understand.

Comment: @PepeEsteban: TB for comments and OT for this site. Please read and think what happens if you overwrite linker-managed memory (although according to your last comment the latter might not be the case for your specific application - but are your sure?).

Comment: @Olaf "TB for comments and OT for this site" I am sorry but my english is not so well to be able understand what does it mean. And I have decoded TB as text back and OT as Off Topic. But still it does not give me sense. Could you pleas explain maybe in more simple way ?

Comment: TB: Too broad - how would "text back" be even related? - , OT is correct. Sorry, these are common abbreviations, you really should get used to them. Not sure what your problem is, but this is neither the time nor the site for tutoring - that's what too broad implies.

Comment: @Olaf As I said, my english is not very good so I don't understand always all meaning of your words. I don't want to be cheeky, but you are maybe the only one person in this communication, who is using in comments such abbreviations.

Answer (score -1):

It's fine as long as `0x00280000` is a valid address - but you should really consider using `uintptr_t` for storing pointer values if available (instead of `long` in your example).

But `DestinationAddress` is an integer. So, you'd need to convert it with a case (otherwise, a compiler might warn about it):

```
temp = (long*)DestinationAddress;
*temp = Data32;
```

Comment: Without further information, this is not ok, but invokes UB.

Comment: @usr yes it is valid address (RAM memory). If I dont have 'uintptr_t' available?   How did you change format of my "code"?

Comment: @Olaf what does it mean UB?

Comment: `[u]intptr_t` is available since C99. If you don't have it then you need to be careful about truncation (if the value doesn't fit in the type you are using). Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for formatting markers/shortcuts.

Comment: @PepeEsteban: Memorise this abbreviation, it means _undefined behaviour_ - look it up!

Comment: @usr So I have found in the settings the paramater Enable C99 extensions but also after enabling and apllying this change, I got error when compiling. It looks like it is still not recognized